# Why my SlidingTab scrollbar color does not change and always return on the position 0

Tags: android

[image]What is wrong with this code? After I clicked tab page 2, it loads the data and the scrollbar color below does not change, and always returns to tab page 1. What should I do? All I want is to indicate by scrollbar color which tab is selected after I click which page I want.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    titlebar = getIntent().getStringExtra("Branch");
    setTitle( titlebar +" Order" );
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity



    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {


                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);

        }
    });
    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);



    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pagelistener);
    pagelistener.onPageSelected(0);



}


final ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pagelistener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (position==0){

            new LoadProducts().execute();


        }else if(position==1){

            new LoadCart().execute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
};
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.work.mcoatorderingapp;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;


public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


// Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
    super(fm);

    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

}

//This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
    {
        OrderTab ordertab = new OrderTab();
        return ordertab;
    }
    else if(position==1)     // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
    {
        ViewOrderTab viewordertab = new ViewOrderTab();
        return viewordertab;
    }
    else
    {
        OrderStatus orderstatus = new OrderStatus();
        return orderstatus;
    }

}

// This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position];
}

// This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}


public static interface FirstShot
{
    public void onFirstShot();
}

}
```

Comment: Post your code for ViewPagerAdapter

Comment: Please check the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pagelistener)`, instead do this `tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(pagelistener)`

i.e instead of creating and assigning `OnPageChangeListener` for `ViewPager`, create and assign one for `SlidingTabLayout` to listen for its event.

Below is the portion from `SlidingTabLayout.java` found on android sample project explaining the part.

```
     /**
     * Set the {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are
     * required to set any {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
     * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
     *
     * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
     */
     public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
     }
```

Also setOnPageChangeListener is deprecated, use [addOnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)) instead of that in your code.

Comment: My main problem is when i click my desire tab the color below that tab does not change and always return to tab 1, i dont have problem in loading data.

Comment: please check my problem above

Comment: You should not add listener to pager, add it to SlidingTabLayout. Did you try that?

Comment: Also setOnPageChangeListener is deprecated, use addOnPageChangeListener instead. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)

Comment: Can you provide some examples because I'm new in android development

Comment: Example for ? I mean for which part